# Getting a single total sum after iterating through a List

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I am calculating the sum of the price in my List by iterating through with a for loop but it returns the total in a list too. If you don't understand, this is my code for trying looping through the list.

```
  public class CartAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Cart> {

private Activity context;
private List<Cart> carts;

public CartAdapter(@NonNull Activity context, ArrayList<Cart> carts) {
    super(context, R.layout.cart_list_item, carts);
    this.carts = carts;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    View cartViewItems = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_list_item, null, false);

    TextView textViewName = cartViewItems.findViewById(R.id.cart_item);
    TextView textViewPrice = cartViewItems.findViewById(R.id.cart_price);
    ImageView imageViewCart = cartViewItems.findViewById(R.id.cart_img);

    Cart cart = carts.get(position);
    textViewName.setText(cart.getName());
    textViewPrice.setText(String.valueOf(cart.getPrice()));
    Picasso.with(context).load(cart.getImg()).into(imageViewCart);

    countCart(textViewPrice);

    return cartViewItems;
}

public double countCart(TextView textViewPrice){
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < carts.size(); i++) {
        sum = sum + Double.parseDouble(textViewPrice.getText().toString());
    }
    System.out.println("Count Price: " + sum);

    return sum;
}
```

}

and the size of my list at the moment has 2 items inside and this is the output for it.

> 08-10 09:38:15.771 6285-6285/com.zack.tinga.applicationtest I/System.out: Count Price: 23.98
>
> 08-10 09:38:15.790 6285-6285/com.zack.tinga.applicationtest I/System.out: Count Price: 23.98

The price is correct but the problem is that it returns the sum using the size of the list. How can I make it to return just a single sum after iterating through the list. e.g. if the size of the list is 15, then it will print the sum 15 times on the output, which it should just print it once.

This is the screenshot of the app:

[image: app screen shot]

So it should display a single total, not list.size(); times as it currently does.

Comment: show your full code may be call 2 times

Comment: This makes no sense.  Where are you iterating through the list?  What haven't you shown us?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem the for loop there is used to iterate through the list.

Comment: @Hasmukhkachhatiya it's not called twice, the for loop is the one that calculates the sum.

Comment: @Zack, no, it really isn't.  You're not using `i` inside the `for` loop at all, so nothing is being iterated.

Comment: ok but for which value ?every time it gets same value according to your list size

Comment: You must be calling the method `countCart()` multiple times. Pls check or post that part of the code.

Comment: I just updated the code now, I'm only calling it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try by having a `boolean` to check if it has already printed on not.

First declare a variable in your class:

```
private boolean isPrinted = false;
```

then in your `getView` method check like this:

```
 if(!isPrinted)
{
countCart(textViewPrice);
isPrinted = true;
 }
```

This will  make this statement to run just once and wont run according to the size of the list.

Comment: Wow buddy, it works like magic, Thanks very much!! You just helped after a long week of suffering..

Answer (score 2):

The issue is:

You are calling the method `countCart(textViewPrice)` **inside** the `getView()` method of the Adapter which is called multiple times (equal to number of rows visible at a time in the ListView and also while scrolling the ListView).

Hence you gotta **call** `countCart(textViewPrice)` somewhere **outside** the `getView()` method.